# Using unordered_map<size_t, unordered_set<string>> to find collisions

Tags: c++, hash, collision-detection, unordered-map, unordered-set

Could someone please help me to understand how can i use the temporary unordered_map<size_t, unordered_set> to find collisions parsing from these parameters of the function:

```
template <typename Hash>
int CollisionsCounter(const Hash& hasher, istream& text) {

}
```

This kind of problem has been discussed already in this [thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403972/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-unordered-map) but the provided solution based on unordered_set. My problem is tht i dont' understand if i should cast a "hasher" to size_t somehow or this "size_t" Key type refers to smth else? But if i am asked to use "hasher" as a key for this temporary U-map than how to do tht if there is size_t type ? I have only started to study hash-tables, unordered_map, so i apologize if my question is silly or sounds so. The full task looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template <typename Hash>
int FindCollisions(const Hash& hasher, istream& text)
{


}

struct HasherDummy
{
    size_t operator() (const string& str) const {
        size_t res = 0;
        for (char c : str) {
            res += static_cast<size_t>(c);
        }
        return res;
    }
};

struct DummyHash
{
    size_t operator()(const string&) const {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{

    DummyHash dummy_hash;
       hash<string> good_hash;

       {
           istringstream stream("I love C++"s);
           cout << FindCollisions(dummy_hash, stream) << endl;
       }

       {
           istringstream stream("I love C++"s);
           cout << FindCollisions(good_hash, stream) << endl;
       }

}
//Output:
//2
//0
```

I tried to implement the solution from the same question asked some time ago (the link has been provided) but so far it doesnt work properly.

Comment: Are you looking for _hash_ collisions? Or are you looking for _table_ collisions? Different hash values may collide, depending on the size of the table.

Comment: Hash collisions . Basically, the task is stated as follows: The hasher will be passed as one of the parameters. The text must be read word by word from the istream. A collision is a situation when a parsed word that has not appeared before has the hash coinciding with the hash of one of the previous words.

Comment: So you need to _count_ collisions per hash? That's the only reason to use unordered_map. Otherwise use unordered_set.

Comment: I a m suggested to use the unordered_map<size_t, unordered_set> as tmp container. I totally understand the issue when it comes to using the unordered_set, but i m trying to figure out wt to do with the key for the container i mentioned in the first sentence. I mean wt does size-t should correspond to ? How to use bucket.size() or bucket.count() i pretty much understand. The problem is with the key in the reference to unordered_map key of the type size_t. I kinda doubt i should put a hash there, bit if i must then i cant figure out how since we have a template hasher provided by the reference

Comment: `size_t` is just the hash. If all you want to do is test your hash function for collisions, you can just create `unordered_set<size_t>` and insert values from your hasher. _e.g._ `if (!my_set.insert(HasherDummy()("I love C++"s)).second) ++collision_count;`

Comment: Oh... thank you, now i think i start to understand the idea .  Thank you so much for the help and suggestions.